# How to merge names using R?

Tags: r, if-statement, merge, dataframe

I have a dataframe (`day`) with columns that looks like this:

```
AM Monday
PM Monday
AM Tuesday
PM Tuesday
...
```

I am trying to create another column that looks like this:

```
Mon_AM
Mon_PM
Tue_AM
Tue_PM
...
```

Essentially, I am trying to merge the two columns together into one. I tried using an if statement like this:

```
if (day$time == 'AM' & day$day == 'Monday') {
day$session == 'Mon_AM'
}
```

but this seems kind of bulky, and it didn't seem to be working.
Does anyone know another way to do this? Looked into the `merge` command but was confused. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know the exact syntax for this case but look into the paste function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strtrim` to get the first three letters of the weekdays and then `paste` to paste the columns together:

```
paste(strtrim(day[[2]], 3), day[[1]], sep = "_")
#[1] "Mon_AM" "Mon_PM" "Tue_AM" "Tue_PM"
```

Comment: thanks these both worked well! the `strtrim` was very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways (this uses `substr` now as I missed the need for abbreviation in the orig q):

```
dat <- data.frame(when=sample(c("AM", "PM"), 25, replace=TRUE),
                  day=weekdays(.leap.seconds))

head(dat)
##   when       day
## 1   PM    Friday
## 2   PM    Sunday
## 3   PM    Monday
## 4   AM   Tuesday
## 5   PM Wednesday
## 6   AM    Friday

sprintf("%s_%s", substr(dat$day, 1, 3), dat$when)
##  [1] "Fri_PM" "Sun_PM" "Mon_PM" "Tue_AM" "Wed_PM" "Fri_AM" "Sat_PM"
##  [8] "Sun_PM" "Mon_AM" "Tue_PM" "Wed_PM" "Thu_PM" "Sun_PM" "Thu_AM"
## [15] "Sun_PM" "Mon_AM" "Tue_PM" "Wed_PM" "Thu_PM" "Sun_AM" "Mon_AM"
## [22] "Thu_AM" "Sat_AM" "Wed_AM" "Sat_AM"

paste0(substr(dat$day, 1, 3), "_", dat$when)
##  [1] "Fri_PM" "Sun_PM" "Mon_PM" "Tue_AM" "Wed_PM" "Fri_AM" "Sat_PM"
##  [8] "Sun_PM" "Mon_AM" "Tue_PM" "Wed_PM" "Thu_PM" "Sun_PM" "Thu_AM"
## [15] "Sun_PM" "Mon_AM" "Tue_PM" "Wed_PM" "Thu_PM" "Sun_AM" "Mon_AM"
## [22] "Thu_AM" "Sat_AM" "Wed_AM" "Sat_AM"

paste(substr(dat$day, 1, 3), dat$when, sep="_")
##  [1] "Fri_PM" "Sun_PM" "Mon_PM" "Tue_AM" "Wed_PM" "Fri_AM" "Sat_PM"
##  [8] "Sun_PM" "Mon_AM" "Tue_PM" "Wed_PM" "Thu_PM" "Sun_PM" "Thu_AM"
## [15] "Sun_PM" "Mon_AM" "Tue_PM" "Wed_PM" "Thu_PM" "Sun_AM" "Mon_AM"
## [22] "Thu_AM" "Sat_AM" "Wed_AM" "Sat_AM"

sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(i) { pystr::pystr_format("{1}_{2}", dat$when[i], substr(dat$day[i], 1, 3)) })
##  [1] "PM_Fri" "PM_Sun" "PM_Mon" "AM_Tue" "PM_Wed" "AM_Fri" "PM_Sat"
##  [8] "PM_Sun" "AM_Mon" "PM_Tue" "PM_Wed" "PM_Thu" "PM_Sun" "AM_Thu"
## [15] "PM_Sun" "AM_Mon" "PM_Tue" "PM_Wed" "PM_Thu" "AM_Sun" "AM_Mon"
## [22] "AM_Thu" "AM_Sat" "AM_Wed" "AM_Sat"
```